# MySql Connector/J 5.1.41 not connecting

Tags: java, mysql, classnotfoundexception, mysql-connector

I'm using MySQL Connector/J 5.1.41 to connect to a DB, here's the code I'm using to connect:

```
package DB;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConexionMYSQL {
    public String db="floreria";
    public String url= "jdbc:mysql:/localhost"+db;
    public String user= "root";//aqui va el usuario del phpmyadmin
    public String pwd="";

public Connection conectar(){
    Connection link = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        link = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.user, this.pwd);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: "+e);
    }
    return link;
  }
}
```

I'm a newbie in Java and mysql connections, when I execute the code, It shows me the following exception:

> ERROR:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

I've already checked that the jar file is in the classpath, I've reinstalled and replaced the jar file for MySql connector too, but stays the same. As I said, I'm new in this world, I barely know about JavaFX and mysql connections, so thats all info I think I can provide, here's an image from my classpath, maybe there's the problem:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need `Class.forName`, I'm not sure if the `url` is the only problem - but `public String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+db;` - is `mysql` configured to allow `root` access from `localhost` (or even to listen to TCP)?

Comment: I'm using xampp for the managment of the Data Base, I'm using phpMyAdmin for that, I can login with "root" with any problem. I don't know if that's what you mean.

Comment: @M.Sha2 check my answer,i think it will be helped to you and please accept if it is useful to you :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

**First** :
 Change this line from :  `public String url= "jdbc:mysql:/localhost"+db;` to  `public String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+db;`

**Second** : 
 This is a strange driver name : `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`
This is the one I know of : `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` so you can change line from : 
 `Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");`  to this one :`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
**EDIT**: Mistake on the driver name, I've corrected it.

Make sure the jar files are in the classpath.

Good luck.

Comment: You need two slashes before `localhost`. And you haven't needed `Class.forName` for a [*long* time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) - from the **Java 6** JavaDoc link, *Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()` will continue to work without modification.*

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, my bad

Comment: If I'm not wrong the second edit you suggest that I change is the same thtat I've already have.

Comment: Yes, in my case, i use netbeans and this driver comes bundled with the IDE so i simply right click and select add library and the choose MYSQL JDBC Driver

Comment: Make these changes and let me know of any errors that may occur

Comment: Yes, I didn't know that MYSQL Driver came bundeled with netbeans, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change `url` like this

```
public String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+db;
```

put a file with MySQL driver to your `classpath` in NetBeans, so the IDE know the driver class you want to load.

The other thing is a strange driver name `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`, usually it is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Please try using the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` driver name and put a `mysql-connector` jar into your `classpath`. You can find the driver in MySQL `JDBC` Connector JAR, which you can download here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

1. Right click on Libraries > Click on Add Library.
2. Scroll down to find MySQL JDBC driver.
3. Press Shift + F11. (Clean and Build)
4. Run

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Change the code like this : public String url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+db;
- Make sure that MySQL Connector/J 5.1.41 jar file placed in the
  class path NOT the zip file.
- unzip the MySQL Connector/J 5.1.41 jar file and make sure that
  this Driver ( org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)  is exist .
- If not, check com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class is Exist and change the
  Driver class as com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.